# Winter Bash 2017 : Authentication screen with http:// URL

Tags: feature-request, bug, ssl, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

When I access the [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) and click the **log in** option in the top bar, I get the following the authentication screen.

There the URL for the winter bash 2017 is **http://**. Can this URL be updated as **https://**

> [image: Authentication screen]

---

**Update:**

Also the same **http://** URL is displaying under the **Edit Profile & Settings -> Applications** page.

> [image: Edit profile - Applications]

Comment: Also, this link is broken until the site is up, which means months every time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to, since the page it redirects to is just HTTP, which is no problem since there is no PII there. The authentication screen used is HTTPS, as it should. (You can see that from the URL in your screenshot)

Moreover, the HTTP page automatically redirects you to the HTTPS variant.

Comment: That is not the point. It's like having a typo. The link is wrong, even if not broken. Agree the bug is very minor and without a real impact, but still a bug.

Comment: No. There is no typo. The link is HTTP, so the text is too.

Comment: See the redirect URI in the URL.

Comment: The real, actual, link is `https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/`. Can also be `https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com`. But any change to that makes this a different, incorrect, link. Or, in the very least, not the actual link, which requires extra useless hop to the server. They can also use URL shortener and give link like `http://goog.le/glgdh` etc, which will "work", but again, useless redirection. Since they moved to https, it's expected they will also edit and update all the links, anywhere. This is just another place where they forgot to do that.

Comment: So then the actual source might be wrong, or there is a browser issue. I can agree that would be useful to fix. The authentication screen isn't wrong indeed.

Comment: I think you still miss the point..